OMNeT++, MEC issue: Cannot resolve address -- in module (VirtualisationInfrastructureManager)
I met an error and wish to find solution. Thank you.
I am running the simulation based on the MEC simulation example in Simu5g. I added a cellular interface in the udp module in MecHost to move it through veinsManager.The code like:
package simu5g.mobileMEC;
module mmecHost extends MECHost
{
    parameters:

    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;


    submodules:
        mobility: <default("")> like IMobility if typename != "" {
            @display("p=86.595,67.77");
        }//"VeinsInetMobility"

    connections:
        radioIn --> upf_mec.radioIn_cellular;
}

In ini file I added some code about veinsManager and mmecHost.
[Config MultiMec]
sim-time-limit=40s
network = MultiMecHost_example
############# Veins Mobility ################
# CA
*.mmecHost[*].cellularNic.numCarriers = 1
*.mmecHost[*].cellularNic.nrChannelModel[0].componentCarrierIndex = 0

# UEs position 
*.ue[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"
*.mmecHost[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"

# VeinsManager parameters
*.veinsManager.host = "localhost"       # if traci-launchd runs on localhost
#*.veinsManager.host = "sumo"       # traci-launchd on different host/container
*.veinsManager.moduleType = "ue=simu5g.nodes.NR.NRUe *=simu5g.mobileMEC.mmecHost"
*.veinsManager.moduleName = "ue=ue *=mmecHost"
*.veinsManager.launchConfig = xmldoc("dublin.launched.xml")
*.veinsManager.updateInterval = 0.2s##########!!!!!!!!!!!

# routing table
#*.ue[*].cellularNic.ip2nic.routingTableModule="^^.ipv4.routingTable"

*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatformManager.mecOrchestrator = "mecOrchestrator" 

# mobile-MEC Hosts
*.mmecHost[*].virtualisationInfrastructure.ipv4.forwarding = true
*.mmecHost[*].maxMECApps = 100                  # max ME Apps to instantiate
*.mmecHost[*].maxRam = 32GB                 # max KBytes of Ram 
*.mmecHost[*].maxDisk = 100TB                   # max KBytes of Disk Space 
*.mmecHost[*].maxCpuSpeed = 400000              # max CPU

*.mmecHost[*].bsList = "gnb1, gnb2"

# MEC Services
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.numMecServices = 0
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.mecService[0].typename = "LocationService"
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.mecService[0].localAddress = "mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure" 
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.mecService[0].localPort = 10020
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.serviceRegistry.localAddress = "mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure" 
*.mmecHost[0].mecPlatform.serviceRegistry.localPort = 10021

*.numMecHost =0

However, when I try to run it. There was the same error:L3AddressResolver: Cannot resolve address MultiMecHost_example.mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure -- in module (VirtualisationInfrastructureManager) MultiMecHost_example.mmecHost[0].vim (id=659), at t=0.2s, event #889
Could anyone help me with this error?
Thank you so much if you can give some advices.
I didn't find the solution and want to solve it.
